# Recursive templated function cannot assign to variable 'state' with const-qualified type 'const tt &'

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I've reduced my code down to the following minimum code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

class tt
{
public:
   bool player;        
   std::vector<tt> actions;
};

template<typename state_t>
int func(state_t &state, const bool is_max)
{
   state.player = true;

   const auto &actions = state.actions;
   if(state.actions.size())
   {
      auto soln = func(actions[0], false);
   }

   return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   tt root;
   func(root, true);

   return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this code, I get

```
test.cpp:14:17: error: cannot assign to variable 'state' with const-qualified type 'const tt &'
   state.player = true;
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
test.cpp:19:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'func<const tt>' requested here
      auto soln = func(actions[0], false);
                  ^
test.cpp:28:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'func<tt>' requested here
   func(root, true);
   ^
test.cpp:12:19: note: variable 'state' declared const here
int func(state_t &state, const bool is_max)
         ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
1 error generated.
```

It is claiming that state is a `const tt &` type. The signature of the templated function is `int func(state_t &state, const bool is_max)`, and there is no `const` in front of the `state_t`. It appears the `const` is somehow being deduced from the recursive call because `actions` is a const-ref vector of `tt` objects. I thought argument deduction ignores `const`? How can this occur?

Answer (score 3):

**Answer is mainly extracted from Scott Mayers *Effective C++* book.**

```
template<typename T>
void f(ParamType param);
f(expr);                // deduce T and ParamType from expr
```

**ParamType is a Reference or Pointer, but not a Universal Reference**

The simplest situation is when ParamType is a reference type or a pointer type, but not a universal reference. In that case, type deduction works like this:

- If expr’s type is a reference, ignore the reference part.
- Then pattern-match expr’s type against ParamType to determine T.

*In argument deduction process it ignores the reference part not the `const` part.*

In your case it is `const auto &actions = state.actions;` which means, for the template argument deduction of `auto soln = func(actions[0], false);` only the reference part is dropped, not the *cv qualifiers*.

Further examples from the book.

```
template<typename T>
void f(T& param);       // param is a reference
```

and we have these variable declarations,

```
int x = 27;             // x is an int
const int cx = x;       // cx is a const int
const int& rx = x;      // rx is a reference to x as a const int
the deduced types for param and T in various calls are as follows:

f(x);                   // T is int, param's type is int&

f(cx);                  // T is const int,
                        // param's type is const int&

f(rx);                  // T is const int,
                        // param's type is const int&
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I got the rules of deduction with templates confused with `auto`. Template deduction, as you showed from the Meyers book, maintains `const`, whereas `auto` does not. Never mind. I don't think I'm right here either. I'll check and revisit this comment.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @aep's answer, If it had been deduced as `tt` instead of `const tt`, the compiler would generated an error too, because it is not possible to bind `const reference` to `non-const reference` without `const_cast`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

class tt
{
public:
   bool player;        
   std::vector<tt> actions;
};

void try_to_bind_const_reference_to_non_const_reference( tt& t )
{

}

template<typename state_t>
int func(state_t &state, const bool is_max)
{
   state.player = true;

   const auto &actions = state.actions;
   if(state.actions.size())
   {
      // auto soln = func(actions[0], false);
      try_to_bind_const_reference_to_non_const_reference( actions[0] );
   }

   return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   tt root;
   func(root, true);

   return 0;
}
```

[run online](https://onlinegdb.com/B1ds8kWE8)